# Surface that contain a line which is not a principal direction

Tags: differential-geometry

So I tried looking at level surfaces to find such an example, but I wasn't able to generate one. Could someone suggest some possible surfaces with this attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the quadratic saddle, i.e. the graph of $f(x,y) = x^2 - y^2$. The principal directions at the origin are the $x$ and $y$ axes, but this graph contains the line $\{(t,t,0) | t \in \mathbb R\}$, which is the diagonal line $x=y=0$.